# Lack of consistency with passwordRecovery control!

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I have 3 controls:Login, CreateUserWizard (which works fine) and PasswordRecovery Control.

I registered in CreateUserWizard control. Logged in and everything was fine!, but then when i used the passwordRecovery control, it gave me both of these:
Login name:NewOrder
Password:v9+.?&lxmnh2

That wasnt my password at all, when i try to login again with that password or with my old password, i cant login. When i try to register in the CreateUserWizard control, it tells me that i am already a member, and i need to choose a different name!!

Why is this happening, how can i login or get a new password?

lol, i am not even in the aspnet_Users field in aspmeddb..

Comment: You probably mispasted the new password.  Check for trailing spaces.

Comment: But why when i use the PasswordRecovery control, i cant make the same procedure twice?.. i have my user name, why cant i recover the pass twice?

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: The passwordRecovery doesnt work properly, i enter my login name ("NewOrder") and it tells me that i dont exist. But i do?!?!

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong.  It does work.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are encrypting the passwords when creating a user on the website. If the passwords are encrypted before going into the database then the PasswordRecovery control will only send out a new password for you to use.

Comment: where do i see if the password was encrypted?

Comment: In Web.config.  However, you **must** hash your passwords.

Comment: okay, i changed the way it works. when i put my name into Password recovery control, it will redirect me to a password reset page..there i will do what i need to do. But why when i put my name in the createUserWizard control it tells me that i already exist and when i put my name in the PasswordRecovery control, it tells me that i dont exist :(